# Return value after throwing exception

Tags: java

```
public double get_volume(int a){
  try{
    if (a < 0) {
      // this gets caught in the catch block
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only Positive Numbers & no Letters Please!"); 
    }
    return a*a*a;
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

If this function receives a negative value, it will throw an exception to say that it is not allowed. Else, it will proceed to calculate the volume. Somehow I still have to return some value but is it really needed? How do i write this code correctly?

Comment: uh, manually throwing while simultaneously catching it to print the exception doesn´t really make sense here.

Comment: even if you return, you won't be able to use that value when exception is thrown.

Comment: Okay, you've caught the exception and handled, great, now what is the method suppose to do?  It's required to return a value of some kind

Comment: `Int` wouldn't support letters anyway, also, why not just get the absolute value before multiplying to protect against the fringe case?

Comment: `0` is not a positive number! Message must be `No negative numbers & no Letters Please!`

Answer (score 8):

If you are catching the exception inside the method without throwing any exception to the caller (as you currently do), you must return some default value in your catch block.

It would probably make more sense not to catch the exception within the method, which will allow you not to return anything when the exception is thrown. It will also inform the caller they passed invalid input.

```
public double get_volume(int a)
{
    if (a < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only Positive Numbers & no Letters Please!"); 
    }
    return a*a*a;      
}
```

Now it's the responsibility of the caller to handle the exception.

Note that since `IllegalArgumentException` is an unchecked exception (since it is a sub-class of `RuntimeException`), you don't need to declare that your method `throws` this exception. It would be helpful, though, to describe in the Javadoc when you are throwing this exception.

Comment: you don't think that the OP want to print his message before `System.out.println(e.getMessage());`

Comment: @YCF_L If the OP wants to print the error message within the method, there is no need to do it in an exception handler. You can simply `System.out.println("Only Positive Numbers & no Letters Please!")` before throwing the exception. However, I don't see the point of doing that.

Answer (score 4):

You're not really throwing an exception if you're also catching it in the same method. I think you've meant to do something like:

```
public double get_volume(int a) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (a < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only Positive Numbers & no Letters Please!");
    }
    return a * a * a;
}
```

Comment: you don't think that the OP want to print his message before `System.out.println(e.getMessage());`